# How to use carousel & tab in Nested list example

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, nested-lists

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/nestedlist/

In nested listing i have
Home , when i click on that i moved to Product in that product i have to display tab carousel or tab. But i'm unable to manage.

We have this carousel

```
// Create a Carousel of Items
   var carousel = new Ext.Carousel({
  defaults: {
           cls: 'card'
            },

  items: [{
           html: '<p>Navigate the two carousels on this page by swiping left/right or          
           clicking on one side of the circle indicators below.</p>'
          },
         {
           title: 'Tab 2',
           html: '2'
          },
         {
           title: 'Tab 3',
           html: '3'
         }]
    });
```

In nested listing i'm giving

```
{
text: 'Wer sind Wir',
items:
[ carousel ]
}
```

It neither gives error. So how can we call it?

Comment: Can you paste your code in entirety? I think this should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

In the nested list call a `detailCard` of type `Ext.Panel`

In that panel add your carousel to the items array.